# Can I define a new character for my OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, special-characters, characters

Normally when I write `u+0022` it writes **`"`** (Look [here](http://text-symbols.com/upside-down/)). Is there any way to define a new character? I mean can I design a character and define a value (`u+9999`, for example) to it in order to make OS replace `u+9999` with my character?

Comment: Don't use u+9999 - there are [Unicode private use areas](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you need is a font editor. There are several font editors available for Windows, both freeware and commercial products. Find an unused code in your font of choice, define the appearance of your character, and replace the font file with your modified one. This of course would have to be done for every font you plan to use.

Comment: How to set `u+9999` to the character?

Comment: You don't set a code to the character. You define the character (graphic rendition - the "glyph") for the code. Glyphs do not exist in some space independent of the character codes. As Nils said a little while ago, you can change existing glyphs. It's less invasive to pick an unused code, though.

Answer (score 0):

A good Font Editor is *Type Light*. You then:

- select the unicode point `u+9999` (`"`) on the right side,
- you edit that char,
- you save the font (you need to rename it under menu *font* -> *rename font...*),
- you install the font by doubleclicking it,
- you set up your editor to use the font.